# Convert stored procedure to LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities, linq-query-syntax

I'm using MVC3 and still learning LINQ. I'm having some trouble trying to convert a query to LINQ to Entities. I want to return an Json method

My stored procedure

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[ResourceReports]
(
    @EmployeeID int
) 
as
begin
    select   p.projectName AS Projects,  count( b.[CreatedByID]) AS Bugs
    from [EmployeeDetails] e inner join [Bugs] b  on e.[EmployeId] = b.[CreatedByID]
    inner join Projects p on b.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
    where e.[EmployeId] = @EmployeeID   
    group by P.projectName
end
```

What I have is a few tables, I started writing this out in LINQ but I'm not sure how to properly return the correct type or cast this.

My controller

```
public JsonResult Getchart()
{
    var Bug = db.Bugs.ToList<Bug>();
    var EmployeDetails = db.EmployeeDetails.ToList<EmployeeDetail>();
    var projects = db.Projects.ToList<Project>();

    var result = (from e in EmployeDetails 
                  join b in Bug on e.EmployeId equals b.CreatedByID
                  join p in projects on b.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
                  where e.EmployeId = @EmployeId
                  group p.projectName
                  select new (p.projectName as Project ,count(b.CreatedByID) as Bug)).Take(50);

    return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How will I pass the parameter to for the query, want the data to be returned in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public JsonResult GetChart()
            {
                //int employeeId
              var Bug = db.Bugs.ToList<Bug>();
              var EmployeDetails = db.EmployeeDetails.ToList<EmployeeDetail>();
              var projects = db.Projects.ToList<Project>();

              var query = (from e in EmployeDetails
                           join b in Bug on e.EmployeId equals b.CreatedByID
                           join p in projects on b.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
                           where e.EmployeId == 1
                           group new { p, b } by new
                           {
                               p.projectName
                           } into g
                           select new ChartModel
                           {
                               ProjectName = g.Key.projectName,                     

                               bug = g.Count()
                           }).ToList();
              return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

i Got ...

Comment: You shouldn't post a new answer for this considering you have already accepted an answer, update your original question.

Comment: @james.. I had bind the pie chart .now i will bind the BarChart In View Format in littile bit confuse .can u help me

Comment: Best asking another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can pass the value in as a parameter to the method:

```
public JsonResult Getchart(int employeeId)
{
    var Bug = db.Bugs.ToList<Bug>();
    var EmployeeDetails = db.EmployeeDetails.ToList<EmployeeDetail>();
    var projects = db.Projects.ToList<Project>();

    var result = (from e in EmployeeDetails 
                  join b in Bug on e.EmployeeId equals b.CreatedByID
                  join p in projects on b.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
                  where e.EmployeeId == employeeId   // <-- use the parameter here
                  group p by p.projectName into g
                  select new {
                     Project = g.Key,
                     Bug = g.Count() 
                     }
                 ).Take(50);
    return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

BTW I intentionally corrected a few spellings of `Employee`

Comment: @RaghuBandaru - please see the slight syntax change on the group statement.

Comment: @RaghuBandaru - change the = to ==

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need:

```
public JsonResult Getchart(int employeId)
  {
        var Bug = db.Bugs.ToList<Bug>();
        var EmployeDetails = db.EmployeeDetails.ToList<EmployeeDetail>();
        var projects = db.Projects.ToList<Project>();

       var result =   (from e in EmployeDetails 
                      join b in Bug on e.EmployeId equals b.CreatedByID
                      join p in projects on b.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
                      where e.EmployeId == employeeId
                      group p.projectName
                     select new (p.projectName as Project ,count(b.CreatedByID) as Bug)).Take(50);
                       return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

Are you sure you want to do all of those "ToList<>()" calls?  Once you call "ToList<>()", you bring all three of those tables into memory from the database.  If they are large, that could be a performance issue.

Comment: @Sako73..Thank u geven answer

Answer (score 1):

If this is a controller action, you would probably want to pass the ID via the URL. Also, there is no need to call `ToList` on your tables *before* querying, do the query at the database and only pull down the results e.g.

```
public JsonResult GetChart(int employeeId)
{
    var query = (from e in db.EmployeeDetails
                join b in db.Bugs on e.EmployeeId equals b.CreatedById
                join p in db.Projects on b.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
                where e.EmployeeId == employeeId
                group new {p, b} by new {
                    p.ProjectName
                } into g
                select new {
                    Project = g.Key.Name,
                    Bugs = g.Count()
                }).Take(50);
    return Json(query.ToList(), JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @RaghuBandaru change it to `equals` keyword instead

Comment: .yes equals taken but still am getting error JsonRequestBehaviour and select sentence..

Comment: `still getting error` - I can't help you unless you post the error (I haven't tested the code so their could potentially be syntax errors).

Comment: @RaghuBandaru I will...if you can tell me the error you are getting?

Comment: ...in Select Statment error("only assignment call increment decrement and new object Expression can be use as a statment" and JsonRequestBehaviour("does not exist current")

Comment: See updated answer, it was missing an `into g` call after group statement.

Comment: @James... Am getting Runtime Error in Return Statemnet ("Unable to create a constant value of type 'BugTrackerReportcharts.Models.Project'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.")

Comment: @RaghuBandaru in the `select` part try changing `Project = ...` to `ProjectName = ...` and if you get the same error for `Bugs = ...` change that to `BugCount = ...`.

Comment: Just noticed the line `join p in projects on b.ProjectId...` should be `join p in db.Projects on b.ProjectId...`. Try that.

Comment: @James...If you dont mind ..am not getting database values whenever i check in debug in Result View ("Expanding the result view will enumarate the IEnumarable") in Result vie method in came...

Comment: So the query is executing you just aren't getting any results now?

Comment: @james...this query used result show the Gridview ...but client requeremnt in Bind the Pie chat so thats why am doing this type

Comment: @RaghuBandaru I am afraid binding the query to a Pie chart is beyond the scope of your original question. You should ask a different question for that.

Comment: @james... Thank u for helping me ..and response me.ok no issues i will do this work

Comment: @RaghuBandaru no problem, if you are looking for a good charting library you should check out the [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/).